# Problema al añadir un UserControl a un FlowLayoutPanel desde un hilo y con un timer de por medio C# .NET

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, hilos, timer

Tengo un cronómetro con el formato 00:00:00:00 que se visualiza en un label:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para cronometrar utilizo una instancia de la clase Stopwatch `Stopwatch Crono = new Stopwatch();`
Para mostrar el cronómetro en el label utilizo el siguiente timer que se ejecuta cada milisegundo:

```
private void Tmr1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblCrono.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}",
    Crono.Elapsed.Hours, Crono.Elapsed.Minutes,
    Crono.Elapsed.Seconds, Crono.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10
    );
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, en el hilo principal funciona y el label no tiene cortes (no se para a ratos).

Tengo otro hilo que añade un control "UserControl" a un FlowLayoutPanel , a modo de registro. Utilizo el UserControl cómo si de una línea de un RichTextBox se tratara, con la única diferencia que yo, en cada línea registro controles cómo imágenes, no me basta solo con un log de texto.

Hasta aquí todo bien también, entonces ¿Cuál es mi problema?

Mi problema viene cuándo junto estas dos cosas. Cuándo añado el UserControl al FlowLayoutPanel lo necesito hacer por medio de un delegado porque lo estoy intentando añadir desde otro hilo, por eso lo invoco:

```
// Así añado un User Control desde un subproceso
if (InvokeRequired) { Invoke(new Action(() => flpIn1.Controls.Add(us))); } else { flpIn1.Controls.Add(us); }
```

Pero resulta que JUSTO en el momento que se ejecuta esa línea, el timer se para (que no el cronómetro) y cuándo la ha añadido vuelve a continuar. Estos parones son muy rápidos, el objetivo es ejecutar esta última línea de alguna otra forma para que no se pare, o bien otra forma de actualizar el crono con el timer.

Se que es muy largo para tal simplicidad, estoy empezando...

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te recomiendo que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. 
También, aprovecha y haz el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.

Comment: A que te referís con que se bloquee?

Comment: podrias dar algo mas de contexto del problema, ese codigo que nos muestras porque usa el Invoke() ?